# iOS - AVPlayer can't stream video url from https localhost server

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avkit

I'm trying to create a streaming app on iOS. So at first I tried with an http url and it didn't work because of security reasons they say so I created an https server on Android using NanoHTTPD and I'm able to access the new https server with Android and Windows devices connected on the same network albeit with warnings. Now I added this on my Info.plist file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```

But it still remains the same and then I ran the app on the simulator and the logs gave me this

```
    2019-09-21 15:40:07.540419+0800 SampleAVPlayerStream[8746:47938] 80: Failed to set processVolumeScalar on device. Error: 560947818
2019-09-21 15:40:07.859455+0800 SampleAVPlayerStream[8746:47938] TIC SSL Trust Error [1:0x6000017fb480]: 3:0
2019-09-21 15:40:07.877511+0800 SampleAVPlayerStream[8746:47938] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
2019-09-21 15:40:07.881312+0800 SampleAVPlayerStream[8746:47938] Task <8F036D25-D6CC-433E-A61E-CD5A844CFAF5>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1202 [3:-9813])
2019-09-21 15:40:07.886919+0800 SampleAVPlayerStream[8746:47938] Task <8F036D25-D6CC-433E-A61E-CD5A844CFAF5>.<1> finished with error - code: -1202
2019-09-21 15:40:07.900192+0800 SampleAVPlayerStream[8746:48024] Task <8F036D25-D6CC-433E-A61E-CD5A844CFAF5>.<1> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “192.168.0.27” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
    "<cert(0x7fc32a084600) s: Gus Fakelastname i: Gus Fakelastname>"
), NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://192.168.0.27:8080/Videos/heyheyhey.mp4, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://192.168.0.27:8080/Videos/heyheyhey.mp4, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002c9c4b0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1202 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x6000010e8750>, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9813, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=(
    "<cert(0x7fc32a084600) s: Gus Fakelastname i: Gus Fakelastname>"
)}}, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <8F036D25-D6CC-433E-A61E-CD5A844CFAF5>.<1>"
), _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <8F036D25-D6CC-433E-A61E-CD5A844CFAF5>.<1>, NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x6000010e8750>, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “192.168.0.27” which could put your confidential information at risk.} [-1202]
```

Update: This is the logs if I revert the server back to http

```
    2019-09-21 19:12:37.829817+0800 SampleAVPlayerStream[4270:23381] Task <D17E6DB2-73F5-4C8D-92B7-A10B0EECD8BD>.<1> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.0.27:8080/Videos/heyheyhey.mp4, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.0.27:8080/Videos/heyheyhey.mp4, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <D17E6DB2-73F5-4C8D-92B7-A10B0EECD8BD>.<1>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <D17E6DB2-73F5-4C8D-92B7-A10B0EECD8BD>.<1>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled} [-999]
2019-09-21 19:12:37.826346+0800 SampleAVPlayerStream[4270:23254] Task <D17E6DB2-73F5-4C8D-92B7-A10B0EECD8BD>.<1> finished with error - code: -999
```

Here is the Swift code.

```
if let urlVal = NSURL(string: "https://192.168.0.27:8080/Videos/heyheyhey.mp4") {
        let player = AVPlayer(url: urlVal as URL);
        let vc = AVPlayerViewController();
        vc.player = player;

        present(vc, animated: true) {
            vc.player?.play();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's really `https`? The message says certificate is invalid and it's probably so. Try use `http` in your url instead.

Comment: @inokey it is https, I turned it into an https server on NanoHTTPD.

Comment: Try use `http` instead in your Nano HTTPD and check if it's working.

Comment: @inokey I updated the question to include the logs if I turn it back to http. Still has errors but it's different this time, check it out.

Comment: great. Now share the code when you use this. From my experience this error often comes when instance that requests resource is deallocated before the result comes in.

Comment: @inokey posted the swift code.

Comment: you still have https in the url, even though you said you changed the server to http.

Comment: @inokey I changed it to http then switched it back to https.

Comment: CFNetwork error -1202 indicates the server certificate is untrusted. You will have to implement custom certificate trust evaluation if this is a self signed certificate. Look into AVAssetResourceLoader and custom resource loading.